# Unexpected IP Address When Using NSLookup

Tags: networking, windows-10, dns, vmware, nslookup

My desktop is running Windows 10 Enterprise 64-bit along with an ASUS RT-N56U router. My router's DHCP range is from 192.168.3.2 through 192.168.3.100 and the gateway is at 192.168.3.1. But this desktop computer is assigned a static IP address of 192.168.3.101--and I have confirmed that using ping and IPConfig.

When I use NSLookup on the desktop machine and cite the name of the desktop computer (let's call it TEMP), I am getting an IP address that's totally unexpected because it's not the static IP address of the local machine. Issuing NSLOOKUP TEMP returns 23.202.231.169 and 23.217.138.110.

Why would that happen?

I am posting this as a precursor question to troubleshooting an issue that's preventing me from seeing other computers on my network by name (I can see them by IP address) so I think I've got a DNS issue.

My computer is not part of a home group; I have tried renewing, flushing the DNS cache, and resetting my IP address using IPConfig; I have rebooted the computer as well as router.

I have invested *hours* trying to investigate why this would occur--and have read many postings on this subject, to no avail. I am admittedly nearing my wit's end. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is your router your DNS server?

Comment: I would have to say yes because I am able to browse external websites only if I ensure that my primary DNS is 192.168.3.1--which is the gateway address to my router.

Comment: For what it's worth, I do think the router configuration is now suspect. This is a new problem and seems to have appeared after I had tried to configure a VPN using my router. I gave up on that, and thought I had set everything back to the way it was. I am trying to avoid resetting the router to manufacturer defaults. Also, I'd really like to know how NSLookup can return an IP address that's not even on my subnet...!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nslookup querying DNS server to return IP address to hostname or vice versa.
DNS doesnt see your private address it sees only public ip addresses. These addresses that you provided are from Akamai which is content delivery network so I bellive your ISP using them to conect with rest of the internet and Akamai provided your ISP with some public IP addresses including those 2: 23.202.231.169 and 23.217.138.110.

Comment: That makes sense. Can you suggest why my Windows desktop cannot resolve the name of the local computer name to the local static IP address when the DNS IP address for the active ethernet adapter specifies my router's gateway IP address?

Comment: AT&T did have to replace my modem about a week ago--my router sits behind that. I turned off that modem's Wifi (it's a modem/router but I have my own router). Do you think I need to change a setting on the AT&T modem? If so, what setting would that be? My router sat behind the old modem using the same connections, so I didn't think I'd need to worry about any modem settings interfering with my network...

Comment: OK, I read more on this site and it turns out that AT&T default DNS will resolve an unknown IP address to the Akamai address range. So I configured my WAN setting in my router to point to Google's DNS servers instead--now I get a "can't find TEMP" when I use NSLookup TEMP. That's more like it. I'd rather have that then have it resolve to a external IP address. Now I can troubleshoot why the NSLookup fails... :)

Comment: Yes, that Ping worked. I will post a new message in a moment to continue troubleshooting.

Comment: If your adapter pointing to your router as DNS server your router in fact (in most cases) act like DNS proxy server so when your router will get DNS query he will just forward this to another (real) DNS server thats why your router do not resolving hostnames. If you want resolve name to ip address you can use old and good ping command just type "ping -a 192.168.3.101" and should resolve your IP address to actual hostname you will see: "Pinging DESKTOP-NAME [192.168.3.101]".
//adding comment again because missclick :D

Comment: OK, to be able to fairly award another answer, I've created a follow-up question here: https://superuser.com/questions/1461035/nslookup-unable-to-resolve-local-computers-hostname